# Optimal way of transferring an array of samples

Tags: python, io, data-transfer

I am writing a Python framework for testing probabilistic programs.

For defining probabilistic models and obtaining samples I am using the [WebPPL](http://webppl.org/) programming language.

The workflow is this:

- the user creates a `Distribution` object which is a wrapper over a `.wppl` file:

```py
p = Uniform(lo=1, hi=100)
```

- `sample` will spawn a process which runs the `webppl` binary, generating `/tmp/samples.json` containing the `N` samples which are then loaded as a `numpy` array:

```py
xs = p.sample(N) # N ~ 1e6
```

Things will get messy if `sample` is called at arbitrary / uncertain times (e.g. in a multi-processing environment). Generating unique ids (e.g. `/tmp/samples_<uid>.json`) is not really desirable as a lot of files will be created.

Therefore, my question is: how to efficiently transfer samples from WebPPL to Python?

I cannot get rid of WebPPL (and therefore process creation and I/O overhead), but maybe there's a smarter way of dumping and reading samples without **polluting** `/tmp` (or any other disk location) and ensuring consistency even in a multi-processing environment?

Comment: stdout is fine. You can read many gigabytes of data from stdout.

Comment: @Roy2012 - thanks for the suggestion. Since WebPPL is JS-based, I am thinking of using `console.dir(xs, {'maxArrayLength': null})`. It seems to dump 5e6 samples without any problems. Are there any subtle caveats of using this?

Comment: Just make sure you start reading the output from the sub process while it’s still running, so that the buffer between the two processes won’t fill up. If it does, the child process will wait (forever, if you don’t read).